Kafka Consumer using kafka-python is only reading the first message.It's not reading the remaining messages
I am trying to create a consumer using AWS Lambda (with kafka-python). I have an event listener which listens to AWS MSK and invoke a lambda function.
The lambda works properly the first time but after that it is not reading the messages.
I followed some adding "auto_offset_reset" to earliest but it is also not working sometimes and it is also reading old data.
Code For Producer
from kafka import KafkaProducer
from kafka.errors import KafkaError
from typing import Any
import logging
import json
import os

log = logging.getLogger("kafka")

BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS = os.environ.get("KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS", "").split(",")
TOPIC_NAME = os.environ.get("TOPIC_NAME", "demo_testing1")




def put_data_in_kafka(data) -> None:
    try:
        producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS)
        future = producer.send(
            TOPIC_NAME,
            value=bytes(json.dumps({"data": data}), "utf-8"),
            key="api_consumer_key".encode("utf-8"),
        )
        producer.flush()
        meta_data = future.get(timeout=10)
        print(
            f"Topic{meta_data.topic}, Partition{meta_data.partition}, Offset{meta_data.offset}"
        )
    except KafkaError as KE:
        log.exception(f"Failed to send message to Kafka. Error: {KE}")
    except Exception as E:
        log.exception(f"Failed to send message to Kafka. Error: {E}")
    producer.close()


def handler(
    events: dict[str, Any], context: Any
) -> dict[str, Any] | None:
    print(f"{events=}")
    data = events["body"]
    print(data)
    put_data_in_kafka(data)
    response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        "body": json.dumps({"message": "Data Entered Successfully in Kafka Topic"}),
    }
    return response


Code For Consumer
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
from typing import Any
import os

BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS = os.environ.get("KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS", "").split(",")
TOPIC_NAME = os.environ.get("TOPIC_NAME", "demo_testing1")


def handler(event: dict[str, Any], context: Any) ->None:
    try:
        consumer = KafkaConsumer(
            TOPIC_NAME,
            auto_offset_reset="latest",
            bootstrap_servers=BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS,
            consumer_timeout_ms=1000,
            group_id='new_consumer_group2'
        )
        print('Consumer Created Successfully!')
        consumer.poll(timeout_ms=1000)
        for msg in consumer:

            key = msg.key.decode('utf-8') if msg.key else None
            if key != 'api_consumer_key':
                print("Key is not matching!")
                return
            print(msg.value.decode('utf-8') if msg.value else None)
        
    except Exception as E:
        print("Something Went wrong!")
        print(str(E))

    

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

auto_offset_reset=earliest is supposed to read old, existing data. Otherwise, you'll start at the end of the topic, where you'll only read the next produced events after the consumer starts... Consumers usually poll in a while loop, so using a lambda isn't the best environment for it

If you're triggering the lambda from msk, then read the event parameter. You shouldn't need to import kafka libraries

Thanks @OneCricketeer for the input. I have shifted from lambda to ECS for running consumers.
